# Interactive chart Library for web browser supporting click and drag of points

Tags: d3.js, visualization, bokeh, mpld3

I've developed an application in `pyqt` and `matplotlib` which allows the user to drag and edit plot data and I need to provide the same functionality in a web browser. I've looked at `d3.js` but the learning curve seems too steep for the time I have available.

I need advice on which Library/Framework can deliver my needs. Users should be able to select a number of points on a chart and be able to drag them without any noticeable performance penalty. `bokeh` and `mpld3` seem like good candidates. Can anyone advise if these libraries or any other would work well for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bokeh provides a number of standard mechanisms to enable it, mainly via JavaScript or Python callbacks. There is a number of [drag tools](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#boxselecttool) like BoxSelectTool or LassoSelectTool for which you could define a callback but it is also possible to attach a callback to the canvas or plot's data source object.

Additionally it is possible to add a new functionality to Bokeh by writing your own extensions using TypeScript. See [Bokeh documentation here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html).